# spl_autoload_register conflicting with other autoloads

Tags: php

i have the following code in files

file one has this

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    require_once('' . $class . '.php');
});
```

file two has this

```
require_once('Autoload.php');
```

and file 3 is calling files one and two like this

```
include_once('file1.php');

//some codes
include('file2.php')
```

now for some reason when i run file3.php it is giving me this error

failed to open stream: Failed opening required 'Autoload.php'/home/public_html/folder/file1.php on line 26

now i did some research on sp1_autoload_register and it appears that $class may have been defined in file2 and that is triggering the not found error, I suspect that there is another sp1_autoload_register in file2's autoload.php but the included files in there are ioncubed. how can I know if there are additional sp1_autoload_register functions in the encoded files?

Comment: Do you have the file `Autoload.php` in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can check for any sp1_autoload_register function

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
$class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
if (stream_resolve_include_path($class))
    require_once('' . $class . '.php');
})
```